# How to make sure that fragment.getView() is not null?

Tags: android, fragment

I have an activity which implements the `fragment.getView()` method to get the returned fragment layout made available by the fragment. The problem is that I don't know how to know whether the fragment is ready to prevent the null pointer exception produced by this method.
I have tried `fragment.isAdded()`, `fragment.isVisible()` and `while(fragment.getView()!=null){}...`

Non of these have worked.

Comment: You can perform the action in the Fragment's onStart method, when the view is assured to have been created. That way you don't have to do arbitrary checks.

Comment: `if (fragment.getView() != null)` ?

Comment: while (fragment.getView() != null) won't work cause while you are in the loop, your app doesn't do anything else and the fragment won't create his view.

Comment: Why do you need to get your fragment's view ? An acivity is not supposed to manipulate views if it uses fragments.